# Particle system renders particles without object physics

Tags: particles, physics

I've created a plane with cloth physics to simulate a sheet of paper falling.
I wanna do a rain of pappers.

So, in another plane I put a particle system. In that system, section Render, I selected as Object the sheet of paper.

Now the problem:

The thousands papers created by the particle system don't behave as the cloth.
The system only render the object, without the physics!

Is there a way to create thousands of objects (with any kind of physics) dynamically during the animation and without programming?

Comment: "Is there a way to create thousands of objects (with any kind of physics) dynamically during the animation and without programming?" No.

Comment: Very easy to do in the BGE, but not what you want here...

Comment: @X-27 is is possible to do it in the BGE then keyframe the whole animation, then bring it back and forget about BGE?

Comment: Actually, yes. http://i.stack.imgur.com/tIseR.png

Comment: ok guys. I think the particles way more clean and confortable. But I'll surrender and use bge :)